# Remove anything before primary domain or after forward slash

Tags: regex, linux, shell

How can I extract domain names from the text input below? I tried this but it didn't work as expected:

```
grep -oP '(?<=[.])\w+(?=[.])'
```

Is there anyway to do this in sed/awk or any other Linux command?

Input:

```
netgear.com
myapi.arlo.com
https://updates.netgear.com/arlo
https://bugcrowd-pub.bounty.accellion.net
client-api.arkoselabs.com
```

Output desired:

```
netgear.com
arlo.com
netgear.com
accellion.net
arkoselabs.com
```

Comment: What about international domains like `company.co.uk`?

Comment: Oh my god , I miss something how can I handle that . maybe tried to list all in regex uk or something else ,.

Comment: I think that this subject is too complex to be sensibly handled by a single regex, in particular with the country aspect ... you may want to consider using python, specifically the [ltdextract module](https://pypi.org/project/tldextract/)

Answer (score 0):

I found so many solution thanks Google, Tried to craft my own regex ,

`^((http[s]?|ftp):\/)?\/?([^:\/\s]+)((\/\w+)*\/)([\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)(.*)?(#[\w\-]+)?$`

`[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+($|(?=\/))`

`awk -F"." '{print $(NF-1)"."$NF}'`

Comment: It's probably worth noting that only the middle one, `[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+($|(?=\/))`, does what you're asking ...

Comment: Thanks , someone on the top asking , IF I encounter this url ,.https://subdomain.subdomain.company.co.uk/files

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not only trying to remove the /, you are actually trying to extract the main domain from those URLs.

If you put the input in a file called input.txt, the following works for me on Ubuntu 20.10:

cat input.txt | sed -e 's;.*.([a-zA-Z0-9-]*.[a-zA-Z0-9-]*).*$;\1;'

As a brief explanation:
The domain name "parts" (the words between the dots) can only use numbers, letters and the dash symbol as characters. That pattern can be represented as:
[a-zA-Z0-9-]*

The regex above will match 2 of those, separated by a dot, proceeded by a dot (and possibly a number of characters), and succeeded by either the end of line or a group of characters that are not part of the previous groups. I believe the greedy nature of .* will make sure that only the main domain is captured.

There is probably more robust solutions available too.

Comment: Did you actually **test** that?  **sed: -e expression #1, char 37: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS**

Comment: I did, but it looks like i had a typo. edited and corrected the command